# Sum Numbers in List in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to sum the numbers in list in the `DataFrame`. A `TypeError(int())` argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list') occurred using `sum()` method, and I can't find any better way to do this.

Here's my DataFrame :

```
    movie_id    user_id rating  title
0   1   [1, 2, 5]   [5, 4, 4]   [Toy Story (1995), Toy Story (1995), Toy Story...
1   2   [1, 5]  [3, 3]  [GoldenEye (1995), GoldenEye (1995)]
2   3   [1] [4] [Four Rooms (1995)]
3   4   [1] [3] [Get Shorty (1995)]
4   5   [1] [3] [Copycat (1995)]
5   6   [1] [5] [Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao)...
6   7   [1] [4] [Twelve Monkeys (1995)]
7   8   [1] [1] [Babe (1995)]
8   9   [1] [5] [Dead Man Walking (1995)]
```

I want to sum numbers in each list of column 'rating', and add a column showing the sum for each row. For example : 
`[5, 4, 4] => 13, [3, 3] => 6` etc...

Here's a brief view of my code :

```
s = df.loc[0:0, 'rating'].tolist()
```

output : `[[5, 4, 4]]`

So far I've tried :

```
s = sum(int(i) for i in s)
s
```

but this ended up in a TypeError.

I guess if I could turn the output of s into a list like `[5, 4, 4]` would solve the problem, or is there any better ways to do?

And, since I can only sum a row at a time, is there any way to sum the list of each row at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `sum` to `Series.map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ratings': [[1, 2], [4, 5]]})
df['sums'] = df['ratings'].map(sum)
print(df)
#    ratings  sums
#  0  [1, 2]     3
#  1  [4, 5]     9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
df['rating'].apply(sum)
Out:
6
13
4
..
type: Object
```

- applies the function `sum` to each row in the column `'rating'`.

You can assign it to the `df`:

```
df['sum_rating'] = df['rating'].apply(sum)
```

Comment: what if the columns are dynamic and what if one would want to replace the original list with the sum?

Comment: Hi @AJames, I think the most 'pandas' way to do this is to sum a column and then rename it: `df['rating'] = df['rating'].apply(sum); df.rename(columns={'rating': 'sum_rating'}, inplace=True)` (semicolon here is for a line break). If the column (names?) are dynamic, it is possible to wrap it in a function with the signature like `replace_with_sum(df, target_column_name)`.